# Writing a long append argument

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a clean way to code the append argument in the example below:

```
imgBox$.append("<div class='cellGrip cellGrip_se' title='Drag'></div><div class='cellGrip cellGrip_sw' title='Drag'></div><div class='cellGrip cellGrip_ne' title='Drag'></div><div class='cellGrip cellGrip_nw' title='Drag'></div>");
```

The above works, but for clarity I'd rather write:

```
imgBox$.append("<div class='cellGrip cellGrip_se' title='Drag'></div>
                <div class='cellGrip cellGrip_sw' title='Drag'></div>
                <div class='cellGrip cellGrip_ne' title='Drag'></div>
                <div class='cellGrip cellGrip_nw' title='Drag'></div>");
```

But then I get complaints about unterminated strings.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this...

```
imgBox$.append("<div class='cellGrip cellGrip_se' title='Drag'></div>" +
               "<div class='cellGrip cellGrip_sw' title='Drag'></div>" +
               "<div class='cellGrip cellGrip_ne' title='Drag'></div>" +
               "<div class='cellGrip cellGrip_nw' title='Drag'></div>");
```

or this...

```
imgBox$.append("<div class='cellGrip cellGrip_se' title='Drag'></div>\
                <div class='cellGrip cellGrip_sw' title='Drag'></div>\
                <div class='cellGrip cellGrip_ne' title='Drag'></div>\
                <div class='cellGrip cellGrip_nw' title='Drag'></div>");
```

but the 2nd one will insert all the spaces at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the literal newline

```
imgBox$.append("<div class='cellGrip cellGrip_se' title='Drag'></div> \
                <div class='cellGrip cellGrip_sw' title='Drag'></div> \
                <div class='cellGrip cellGrip_ne' title='Drag'></div> \
                <div class='cellGrip cellGrip_nw' title='Drag'></div>");
```

Personally, I'd much rather do :

```
var arr  = ['se', 'sw', 'ne', 'nw'],
    frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

$.each(arr, function(_, key) {
    var div = $('<div />', {'class':'cellGrip cellGrip_'+key, title: 'Drag'});
    $(frag).append(div);
});

imgBox$.append(frag);
```

Comment: As much as the 2nd method looks "flashy", it's better to build a string and append once, rather than have multiple appends.  Why not iterate to build the string and then append that in one hit afterwards?

Comment: @Archer - It's never better to use a string than to create proper elements, so I fixed that problem with a fragment, which is the proper way to build a collection of elements.

Comment: Yep - now that you've changed it it is better :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `\`.

```
imgBox$.append("<div class='cellGrip cellGrip_se' title='Drag'>a</div> \
                <div class='cellGrip cellGrip_sw' title='Drag'>b</div> \
                <div class='cellGrip cellGrip_ne' title='Drag'>c</div> \
                <div class='cellGrip cellGrip_nw' title='Drag'>d</div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate to build the string and then append it

```
var dir = ["se","sw","ne","nw"];
var divs = "";
for( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
 divs += "<div class='cellGrip cellGrip_"+dir[i]+"' title='Drag'></div>";
}
imgBox$.append(divs);
```

Comment: They've got different class names ;)  Also, it's best to append larger blocks of html than smaller blocks multiple times.

Comment: @Archer - See edit for the string building. `@PSL` - You were correct, I addressed that as well.